# Undefined index: Magento\Framework\App\State with NewRelic module in Magento 2.2.6

Tags: php, magento, magento2, newrelic, magento2.2

I have 2 modules that uses Plugins for `Magento\Framework\App\State::afterSetAreaCode`

Whenever both of the modules are enabled Magento throws:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined index: 
Magento\Framework\App\State in /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/PluginList/PluginList.php on line 250
```

I've followed the code and came to conclusion that the fault seems to be a `Magento\NewRelicReporting\Plugin\StatePlugin::afterSetAreaCode`. This modules and method is calling retrieving some configuration values.
Somehow, retrieving the values load additional configuration files and resets `Magento\Framework\Interception\PluginList\PluginList::_pluginInstances` list which then returns error when next plugin in List in `Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor` tries to call `getPlugin` method.

This seems to happen only when cache is clear, once it's populated the site seems to work, but obviously it's not going to work correctly.

Has anyone ever encountered such issues?

Comment: Did you find a workaround for this? I'm also having the issue

Comment: @DWils - Unfortunately, we've just disabled the NewRelic module. Never found a proper solution

Comment: Ah bummer, still haven't been able to figure out why it's happening but it's probably a plugin conflict in our case as well. Thanks for getting back to me

Comment: @Marrbacca did you find solution with this?